# CMOS settings failure on every power on

Tags: boot, cmos

I'm getting "corrupt CMOS settings" message on every power on. Tried to replace the CMOS battery with new one, it didn't help.
Ideas?

Comment: What is the make/model of your computer?

Comment: Is "corrupt CMOS settings the **exact** error message?

Comment: @DavidPostill, it's custom PC. ASRock motherboard, Intel CPU. I don't remember exact words, but the meaning is this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the latest BIOS issued by the PC manufacturer for your computer model.

This is usually available under Support on the manufactures website. Be sure to obtain the correct BIOS version and to follow the installation instructions exactly.

Doing this will overwrite the corrupt data in the CMOS (BIOS). If you still have the error message after the BIOS upgrade then you may have a hardware issue regarding the CMOS or the Motherboard.